# "failure in processEncodedAnnotation" using Jackson with ScalaModule on Android

Tags: android, json, scala, jackson

I use Scala 2.11.0 with sbt and android-sdk-plugin together with Jackson as the Json Marshaller. When the app tries to deserialize from Json to my Scala case class the following exception occurs on the device:

```
W/dalvikvm﹕ WARNING: could not find annotation member bytes in Lscala/reflect/ScalaSignature;                                                                               
E/dalvikvm﹕ Failed creating annotation element (m=0x41a575c0 n=0x41a575e0 a=0x0 r=0x0)                                                                                      
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: failure in processEncodedAnnotation                                                                                               
W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: failure in processEncodedAnnotation                                                                                               
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredAnnotations(Native Method)                                                                                                      
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.resolveClassAnnotations(AnnotatedClass.java:308)                                                  
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.getAnnotation(AnnotatedClass.java:173)                                                            
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.findAutoDetectVisibility(JacksonAnnotationIntrospector.java:140)                   
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.<init>(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:111)                                                 
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaPropertiesCollector.<init>(ScalaPropertiesCollector.scala:15)                                           
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.introspect.ScalaClassIntrospector$.constructPropertyCollector(ScalaClassIntrospector.scala:24)                          
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.collectProperties(BasicClassIntrospector.java:142)                                        
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:81)                                        
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicClassIntrospector.forDeserialization(BasicClassIntrospector.java:11)                                        
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationConfig.introspect(DeserializationConfig.java:547)                                                            
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:325)                                                     
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCache2(DeserializerCache.java:263)                                                        
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache._createAndCacheValueDeserializer(DeserializerCache.java:243)                                        
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.DeserializerCache.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializerCache.java:193)                                                 
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.hasValueDeserializerFor(DeserializationContext.java:345)                                             
W/System.err﹕ at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.canDeserialize(ObjectMapper.java:2072)                                                                         
W/System.err﹕ at org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.canRead(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:103)                          
W/System.err﹕ at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$AcceptHeaderRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:542)                                               
W/System.err﹕ at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$HttpEntityRequestCallback.doWithRequest(RestTemplate.java:593)                                                 
W/System.err﹕ at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:474)                                                                               
W/System.err﹕ at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:439)                                                                                 
W/System.err﹕ at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:415)                                                                                
W/System.err﹕ at net.gutefrage.android.rest.ScalaRestTemplate$$anonfun$exchange$1.apply(ScalaRestTemplate.scala:22)                                                         
W/System.err﹕ at net.gutefrage.android.rest.ScalaRestTemplate$$anonfun$exchange$1.apply(ScalaRestTemplate.scala:22)                                                         
W/System.err﹕ at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)                                                                                                                       
W/System.err﹕ at net.gutefrage.android.rest.ScalaRestTemplate$$anonfun$genericRestCallForEntity$1.apply(ScalaRestTemplate.scala:31)                                         
W/System.err﹕ at net.gutefrage.android.rest.ScalaRestTemplate$$anonfun$genericRestCallForEntity$1.apply(ScalaRestTemplate.scala:31)                                         
W/System.err﹕ at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.liftedTree1$1(Future.scala:24)                                                                      
W/System.err﹕ at scala.concurrent.impl.Future$PromiseCompletingRunnable.run(Future.scala:24)                                                                                
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)                                                                            
W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)                                                                            
W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm running a similar setup to yours and had the same problem. Running `sbt clean` before running `sbt android:run` seemed to fix the problem. It looks like it's a compiler issue of sorts.

Found that out from here: https://github.com/pfn/android-sdk-plugin/issues/57

Comment: Finally got away from Jackson and Gson and happily using Spray Json (native Scala)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like upgrading android-sdk-plugin to 1.3.2 resolves this issue.